# How to reload Certificate Revocation List (CRL) in nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl, crl

I have set CRL file in nginx with `ssl_crl` directive:

```
ssl_crl /mypath/crl.pem
```

However, I noticed that adding or removing revoked certificates from crl.pem apply only when I restart or reload nginx server.

What is best practice for this? Reloading nginx configuration when crl.pem changes or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just reload nginx when you make any changes to the file. This will cause it to re-read the files without interrupting any existing connections or needing to restart. For example (RHEL/CentOS):

```
service nginx reload
```